# Problem with AsyncMemoizer and future builder

Tags: flutter, firebase, async-await, flutter-futurebuilder

In my flutter firebase app, I am calling a list of posts with a field of authorId. I am using this post.autorId to get the information of a user by using a future builder. The problem is the future builder gets called multiple times and I tried to solve it by using the async package with AsyncMemoizer. Even though this works, it comes with another issue.  AsyncMemoizer gets the information of only the first post author and repeats it for all the other posts in the list. How can the AsyncMemoizer get the information of each post author?

This is the future builder.

```
 SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) {
              Post post = _postsList[index];
              return FutureBuilder(
                future: _fetchData(post.authorId),
                // DatabaseService.getUserWithId(post.authorId),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return PostEnlargedBlurharsh(
                      post: post,
                    );
                  }
                  AccountHolder author = snapshot.data;
                  return PostView(
                    key: PageStorageKey('FeedList'),
                    currentUserId: widget.currentUserId,
                    post: post,
                    author: author,
                    postList: _postsList,
                    showExplore: _showExplore,
                  );
                },
              );
            },
            childCount: _postsList.length,
          ),
        ),
```

This is the AsyncMemoizer code to get the future only once. But instead, it gets one user's information for multiple posts.

```
 Future _fetchData(String authorId) {
    return this._memoizer.runOnce(() async {
      return DatabaseService.getUserWithId(authorId);
      // return user;
    });
  }
```

Comment: you should have multiple memoizers, for example: `Map<String, AsyncMemoizer>` where key is `authorId`

Comment: i understand you but am finding it difficult to implement in inncode with the Mao<String, AsyncMemoizer>. But I tried another solution which Is to run the AsyncMemoizer on each index but still not getting it. memoizer.runOnce(() async {
      return DatabaseService.getUserWithId( _postsList[index].authorId);
      // return user;
    }),